# Is there a way to limit image selection in React Native for iOS to 1:1 ratio squares only?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I am currently building a react native project for iOS, and I am looking to having an image upload similar to what instagram used to have - only squares allowed. I am struggling to get there just from this.

I have been using expo-image-picker's launchImageLibraryAsync:

```
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    quality: 1,
    aspect: [1, 1],
    allowsEditing: true,
});

if (!result.canceled) {
    this.setState({ image: result.assets[0] });
} else {
    this.setState({ image: null });
}
```

My idea is that this would enforce the 1:1 ratio, which I have found to work when the user zooms into their photo to select the portion of the image. However, I have found it to have problems when the user selects like in the image. I want to find some way that forces them to zoom in - every edge of the square must be filled in order for them to click choose.[Example of where problems occur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T4If.jpg)

Comment: Do you use Expo?

Comment: @VasylNahuliak Yes I do

Comment: It's Expo issue, please create the issue in GitHub like https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/10820

Comment: @DanielGoldenberg Were you able to resolve this issue in any way? Did you open an issue with Expo? If so, could you provide a link?